# Get previous issue status in event-handler (Jira 7.x)

Tags: events, event-handling, jira-plugin

I have a Jira plugin that needs to listen to `IssueEvent`s and respond to various status transitions (as in "To Do -> In Progress", "In Progress -> Done", etc.).  In most cases, doing this requires knowing both the current and the previous issue status.  However there's no obvious API for getting the latter bit of information from the `IssueEvent`.

My setup is fairly simple:

```
@Named("myEventListener")
public class JiraChangeListener implements InitializingBean, DisposableBean {
    @ComponentImport
    private final EventPublisher eventPublisher;

    @ComponentImport
    private final CustomFieldManager fieldManager;

    @ComponentImport
    private final IssueManager issueManager;

    @Inject
    public JiraChangeListener(EventPublisher publisher, CustomFieldManager fieldManager, IssueManager issueManager) {
        this.eventPublisher = publisher;
        this.fieldManager = fieldManager;
        this.issueManager = issueManager;
    }

    @EventListener
    public void onIssueEvent(IssueEvent event) {
        Issue issue = event.getIssue();
        long eventType = event.getEventTypeId();
        String issueStatus = issue.getStatusId();  //the *current* issue status

        //[read various internal plugin settings]

        //now handle the event      
        if (eventType == EventType.ISSUE_CREATED_ID) {
            //triggered upon creation; we don't need the old status here
            if (apiAvailable && issueStatus.equals(triggerStatus)) {
                //we can do stuff (apiAvailable) and we should do stuff (issueStatus == triggerStatus)
                doStuff(issue);
            }
        }
        else if (eventType == EventType.ISSUE_GENERICEVENT_ID) {
            //triggered upon any status transition (and possibly other actions); 
            //need to see if the status has actually been modified
            String oldStatus = [???];  //FIXME:  need to get the previous status here
            boolean statusChanged = ! issueStatus.equals(oldStatus);
            if (apiAvailable && statusChanged && issueStatus.equals(triggerStatus)) {
                //we can do stuff (apiAvailable && statusChanged) and we should do stuff (issueStatus == triggerStatus)
                doStuff(issue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the only catch is with the line that goes:

```
String oldStatus = [???];
```

What's the correct way to programmatically get the issue's previous status, or to otherwise identify that the event has been received *because* the issue's status has changed?

Note that I'm working with Jira 7.x.  Support for previous Jira versions isn't a concern.

Answer (score 1):

Found some helpful information [here](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/11991592/how-to-detect-if-a-field-value-was-changed), and put the following together:

```
private String getPreviousStatusId(Issue issue, IssueEvent event) {
    try {
        GenericValue changeLog = event.getChangeLog();

        HashMap<String, Object> fields = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        fields.put("group", changeLog.get("id"));

        List<GenericValue> changes = changeLog.internalDelegator.findByAnd("ChangeItem", fields);
        for(GenericValue changeVal : changes){
            String field = changeVal.getString("field");
            if ("status".equals(field)) {
                return changeVal.getString("oldvalue");
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //if no changes were made to the 'status' field (or we errored out), just return the issue's current status
    return issue.getStatusId();
}
```

Works like a charm.